# Android support fragment animation problems

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have created an app that uses fragment animations for loading and unloading fragments.

I have saved the animation xml files in res/anim folder and passing it in setCustomAnimation method.

The animations worl flawlessly on my Kitkat phone but on my another FroYo phone, no animation takes place and the things just appear normally.

The weird fact is that the view animations are working on both devices.

I have tried setting the hardwareaccelerated attribute to true but that dint solve it either

Can you please help?

Comment: Post your animation XML. I'm assuming you're setting a duration on an AnimationSet (which doesn't work pre-ICS).

Comment: See... I have 5 anim xmls... 4 of them have the flaw you said ie setting duration on the <set>... But on the 5th one its just a simple <translate> animation... How come that doesnt work?

Comment: Again, without seeing it, I can't say.

Comment: Hey I was wrong... It worked... WOW... Thanks... Post it as an answer and Im gonna give you a check... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug on Android pre-ICS where durations set on an `AnimationSet` in XML are not respected. To fix this, apply the animation duration to all child animations in the `AnimationSet` instead.